# Apache high memory usage with Application load balancer

Tags: apache, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, mod-wsgi

We have an ec2 instance 4vcpu and 16gb of ram which is running Apache server with mpm event behind an aws ELB (application load balancer). This server serve just Images requested by our other applications although for most of application we are using cloudfront for caching but one app is directly sending request on server .  Now Apache memory usage reached to 70% every day but it did not come down we have to restart server every time. Earier will old Apache 2.2 version and worker mpm without load balncer we were not having this issue. I have tried different configuration for MPM EVENT and Apache but its not working. Here is apache2.conf

```
Timeout 120   # also tried the timeout with 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 45 # varies this setting from 1 seconds to 300
```

Here is load balancer setting

- Http and https listener
- Idle timeout is 30

Mpm event

```
<IfModule mpm_event_module>
    StartServers            2 
    MinSpareThreads         50 
    MaxSpareThreads         75 
    ThreadLimit                      64
    #ServerLimit               400
    ThreadsPerChild          25
    MaxRequestWorkers        400
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   10000
```

1. When i change MaxRequestWorkers to 150 with MaxConnectionsPerChild  0 and ram usage reached 47 percent system health checks are failed and new instance is launched by auto scaling group. Seems like worker limit is reached which already happend when this instance was working with 8GB Ram.
2. Our other server which are just running with simple django site and django rest frame apis are working fine with default values for MPM and apache configured on installation.
3. I have also tried the configuration with KeepAliveTimeout equals to 2, 3 and 5 seconds as well but it did not work .
4. I have also follow this link [enter link description here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/apache-backend-elb/) it worked somewhat better but memory usage is not coming down.

here is the recent error  log

```
[Fri Dec 04 07:45:21.963290 2020] [mpm_event:error] [pid 5232:tid 139782245895104] AH03490: scoreboard is full, not at MaxRequestWorkers.Increase ServerLimit.
[Fri Dec 04 07:45:22.964362 2020] [mpm_event:error] [pid 5232:tid 139782245895104] AH03490: scoreboard is full, not at MaxRequestWorkers.Increase ServerLimit.
[Fri Dec 04 07:45:23.965432 2020] [mpm_event:error] [pid 5232:tid 139782245895104] AH03490: scoreboard is full, not at MaxRequestWorkers.Increase ServerLimit.
[Fri Dec 04 07:45:24.966485 2020] [mpm_event:error] [pid 5232:tid 139782245895104] AH03490: scoreboard is full, not at MaxRequestWorkers.Increase ServerLimit.
[Fri Dec 04 07:45:25.967281 2020] [mpm_event:error] [pid 5232:tid 139782245895104] AH03490: scoreboard is full, not at MaxRequestWorkers.Increase ServerLimit.
[Fri Dec 04 07:45:26.968328 2020] [mpm_event:error] [pid 5232:tid 139782245895104] AH03490: scoreboard is full, not at MaxRequestWorkers.Increase ServerLimit.
[Fri Dec 04 07:45:27.969392 2020] [mpm_event:error] [pid 5232:tid 139782245895104] AH03490: scoreboard is full, not at MaxRequestWorkers.Increase ServerLimit.
[Fri Dec 04 07:45:28.970449 2020] [mpm_event:error] [pid 5232:tid 139782245895104] AH03490: scoreboard is full, not at MaxRequestWorkers.Increase ServerLimit.
[Fri Dec 04 07:45:29.971505 2020] [mpm_event:error] [pid 5232:tid 139782245895104] AH03490: scoreboard is full, not at MaxRequestWorkers.Increase ServerLimit.
[Fri Dec 04 07:45:30.972548 2020] [mpm_event:error] [pid 5232:tid 139782245895104] AH03490: scoreboard is full, not at MaxRequestWorkers.Increase ServerLimit.
[Fri Dec 04 07:45:31.973593 2020] [mpm_event:error] [pid 5232:tid 139782245895104] AH03490: scoreboard is full, not at MaxRequestWorkers.Increase ServerLimit.
[Fri Dec 04 07:45:32.974644 2020] [mpm_event:error] [pid 5232:tid 139782245895104] AH03490: scoreboard is full, not at MaxRequestWorkers.Increase ServerLimit.
[Fri Dec 04 07:45:33.975697 2020] [mpm_event:error] [pid 5232:tid 139782245895104] AH03490: scoreboard is full, not at MaxRequestWorkers.Increase ServerLimit.
[Fri Dec 04 07:45:34.976753 2020] [mpm_event:error] [pid 5232:tid 139782245895104] AH03490: scoreboard is full, not at MaxRequestWorkers.Increase ServerLimit.
[Fri Dec 04 07:45:35.977818 2020] [mpm_event:error] [pid 5232:tid 139782245895104] AH03490: scoreboard is full, not at MaxRequestWorkers.Increase ServerLimit.
```

Sometime error log has this issue seems like child process is not being killed preoperly by apache

```
[Mon Dec 07 07:04:22.142767 2020] [core:warn] [pid 1836:tid 139752646228928] AH00045: child process 2807 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Mon Dec 07 07:04:24.144831 2020] [core:warn] [pid 1836:tid 139752646228928] AH00045: child process 1847 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Mon Dec 07 07:04:24.144875 2020] [core:warn] [pid 1836:tid 139752646228928] AH00045: child process 2807 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Mon Dec 07 07:04:26.146928 2020] [core:warn] [pid 1836:tid 139752646228928] AH00045: child process 1847 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Mon Dec 07 07:04:26.146967 2020] [core:warn] [pid 1836:tid 139752646228928] AH00045: child process 2807 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Mon Dec 07 07:04:28.149026 2020] [core:error] [pid 1836:tid 139752646228928] AH00046: child process 1847 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
[Mon Dec 07 07:04:28.149092 2020] [core:error] [pid 1836:tid 139752646228928] AH00046: child process 2807 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL
```

top command result

```
3296 www-data  20   0 3300484 469824  58268 S   0.0  2.9   0:46.46 apache2                                               
 2544 www-data  20   0 3359744 453868  58292 S   0.0  2.8   1:24.53 apache2                                               
 1708 www-data  20   0 3357172 453524  58208 S   0.0  2.8   1:02.85 apache2                                               
  569 www-data  20   0 3290880 444320  57644 S   0.0  2.8   0:37.53 apache2                                               
 3655 www-data  20   0 3346908 440596  58116 S   0.0  2.7   1:03.54 apache2                                               
 2369 www-data  20   0 3290136 428708  58236 S   0.0  2.7   0:35.74 apache2                                               
 3589 www-data  20   0 3291032 382260  58296 S   0.0  2.4   0:50.07 apache2                                               
 4298 www-data  20   0 3151764 372304  59160 S   0.0  2.3   0:18.95 apache2                                               
 4523 www-data  20   0 3140640 310656  58032 S   0.0  1.9   0:07.58 apache2                                               
 4623 www-data  20   0 3139988 242640  57332 S   3.0  1.5   0:03.51 apache2
```

What is wrong in the configuration that is causing high memory?

Comment: Note: Stackoverflow is focusing on programming-related questions, not on server configuration/tuning ([help/on-topic]). Also, there definitely is no "optimal configuration" that holds for all cases - they each require individual repeated measurements and tweaking to suit your hardware, network, user load, traffic profile etc.

Comment: @olafKock you right there is no optimum but you can guide me which configuration parameter I need to tweek in mpm_event configuration to stop memory leakage.